# Show realtime data with ng2-charts

Tags: angular, typescript, ng2-charts

I am facing some problem when use ng2 charts to show realtime data, it always show 0 anytime. I have pasted my code snippet down below. Could anyone please help me by checking it and tell me where I have done wrong ?

```
temps: Array<number> = [];
public lineChartData: Array<any> = [[]];  
custom: boolean = false; 
report: boolean = false;  
errMess: any;    
keys: any[] = []    




constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,
private dishService: DishService,){}    
public lineChartLabels: Array<any> = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'];
public lineChartType: string = 'line';
ngOnInit() {
this.dishService.getTemp()
  .subscribe(temps => {
    for (let key in temps[0]) {
      for (var _i = 0; _i < temps.length; _i++) {
        this.keys.push(temps[_i][key]);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.keys);
    this.lineChartData.push(this.keys);
  });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with ng2-charts, you need to manually let angular know that you have updated the data,

do something like this, after the below line,

```
this.lineChartData.push(this.keys);
this.forceChartRefresh();
```

and the function goes as,

```
 forceChartRefresh() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this._chart.refresh();
    }, 10);
  }
```

and you need  a variable inside the component as,

```
@ViewChild(BaseChartDirective) private _chart;
```

**EDIT**

To see the chart updated every 5 minutes, you can use

```
this.interval = setInterval(() => {
    callyour function();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, how to get BaseChartDirective ?

Comment: import { BaseChartDirective } from 'ng2-charts';

Comment: Hi, if i wanna use it to show realtime data, how to do that, if we use forceChartRefresh() the chart will refresh after 5s , it not good for eye. :))

Comment: you need to use $interval

Comment: Could you let me know step by step how to do that ? Thank you.